Does a search bot follow a link in an "a rel href" tag?
On my website, I have internal links marked as "a rel href" instead of "a href." Will google bot follow these links?
I attempted to implement internal links using the "a rel href" format instead of the standard "a href" tag. I expected search bots to follow these links and index the associated pages. However, I suspect the bots might not be recognizing these links as navigational, which could prevent them from being crawled.

If there is no href attribute on the rendered page, then it will be unlikely that bots will follow it.
